# Address Windowing Extensions Overhead

Tags: performance, memory

I just found another SQL Server (2008r2) with AWE enabled on a 64-bit OS/SQL combination.  Has anyone done an research as to the overhead created by enabling AWE on the 64-bit OS/SQL combination?  It is mostly a question of curiosity, though it would be nice to be able to put into the analysis documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone done an research as to the overhead created by enabling AWE on the 64-bit OS/SQL combination?

This is one of the Myths that Paul Randal clearly debunks in his famous series - [A SQL Server DBA myth a day](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-530-awe-must-be-enabled-on-64-bit-servers/)

> On 64-bit systems (2005+): AWE is not required (and in fact enabling it does nothing).

Also refer to [Fun with Locked Pages, AWE, Task Manager, and the Working Set…](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121055642/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/psssql/archive/2009/09/11/fun-with-locked-pages-awe-task-manager-and-the-working-set.aspx) by Bob Ward :

> The AWE APIs for 32bit and 64bit SQL Server systems are used for different purposes. In 32bit it is really to extend memory access beyond 4Gb or to enable the AWE feature. For 64bit systems, it is to possibly gain performance and to “lock pages” for the buffer pool.

and

> In fact, the code for SQL Server for 64bit systems ignores `awe enabled` sp_configure option. It is a “no-op” for 64bit SQL Server systems.